# How To Hide Other User Informations In Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application.
Users can log in to application and they can edit their own profiles.
The problem is; users also can edit other users profile.
For example user's own profile edit link:

```
http://localhost/users/edit/1001
```

But He also can reach other users' profiles like;

```
http://localhost/users/edit/2001
http://localhost/users/edit/10
http://localhost/users/edit/5000
```

Do you have any idea what is the best practice to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The id(1001) in `http://localhost/users/edit/1001` url should be same for logged in user's id(User principal id) then only allow to edit otherwise **403 access denied** page you can redirect.

You can also use PreAuthorize annotation like below.

```
@PreAuthorize("id == authentication.principal.id")
```

Have a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) and [this](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/preauthorize-postauthorize-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can fetch `user_id` from database using Principal and compare it with the passed `user_id` and redirect user to `unauthorized` page if both Ids does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expose the `/edit` endpoint for users...I would create a `/profile/edit` endpoint and always route to the current logged in user and leave the user edit for an admin dashboard, an internal tool.